# Want to use 1 Verilog module output for 2 inputs

Tags: verilog

Everything in my project works perfectly. Basically I use a 2to1mux to determine which of two 7-bit inputs gets displayed on a hex display and 7 LEDs. It works perfectly, but I was wondering how I can use the one 7-bit output from my module for both the LEDs and the Hex display?

Here is my main file:

```
module Majority(SW, LEDR, KEY, HEX0);

    input [16:0] SW;
    
     input [3:3] KEY;
    output [6:0] LEDR;
     output [6:0] HEX0;
    
    my21mux m21m_inst(.sel(KEY[3]), .in0(SW[6:0]), .in1(SW[16:10]), .y(HEX0[6:0]));

endmodule





module my21mux(sel, in0, in1, y);
input sel, in0, in1;
output y;

wire nsel;
wire t1;
wire t2;



not n(nsel, sel);

and a1(t0, in0, sel);
and a2(t1, in1, nsel);

or o(y, t1, t2);

// y should determine which set of switches to display on the LEDs / Hex


endmodule
```

And here is my test bench:

```
`timescale 1 ns/1 ns

module TestBench();
 //stimulus connections   
    reg [3:3] KEY;
    reg [16:0] SW;
    wire [6:0] LEDR;
    wire [6:0] HEX0;
   my21mux S(KEY, SW[6:0], SW[16:10], HEX0[6:0]);
// Test Procedure
    initial begin
KEY[3]=0;SW[10]=0;SW[0]=0; #5;
KEY[3]=0;SW[10]=0;SW[0]=1; #5;
KEY[3]=0;SW[10]=1;SW[0]=0; #5;
KEY[3]=0;SW[10]=1;SW[0]=1; #5;
KEY[3]=1;SW[10]=0;SW[0]=0; #5;
KEY[3]=1;SW[10]=0;SW[0]=1; #5;
KEY[3]=1;SW[10]=1;SW[0]=0; #5;
KEY[3]=1;SW[10]=1;SW[0]=1; #5;
end
endmodule
```

Any ideas would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear how your *main_file* is structured, since there is an unmatched `endmodule` keyword that suggests that you wanted to create some sort of wrapper to your *my21mux* module. Probably that module is not used anyway since in `TestBench` you instantiate `my21mux` mux anyway.

- Quick and dirty solution, 2 muxes:

  ```
    my21mux S_hex0(KEY, SW[6:0], SW[16:10], HEX0[6:0]);
    my21mux S_ledr(KEY, SW[6:0], SW[16:10], LEDR[6:0]);
  ```
- With only one mux instance that has one output, which is assigned to both your signals:

  ```
    wire [6:0] mux_out;
    my21mux S_hex0(KEY, SW[6:0], SW[16:10], mux_out);
    assign HEX0 = mux_out;
    assign LEDR = mux_out;
  ```
- In my opinion the following would be easier, with no need of a custom defined mux:

  ```
    wire [6:0] mux_out = KEY ? SW[6:0] : SW[16:10]; //ternary operator
    assign HEX0 = mux_out;
    assign LEDR = mux_out;
  ```

Please check out [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#Verilog) usage.

Also, in your *my21mux* you associate `in0 AND sel` and `in1 AND nsel`, while the name obviously suggests that it should be the other way round.